# Need to create textboxes dynamically without loosing the style

Tags: c#, asp.net

In my we form, I have a textbox where an integer can be placed and by clicking the button next to it, It should dynamically create that many textboxes as a table. The jQuery code for which is:

```html
$("#ContentPlaceHolder1_LnkBtnNoofItems").click(function () {
        $(".white-table-view-block").removeClass("hide");
        $("#Table-id-Name").removeClass("hide");


        $("#Table-id-Name").each(function () {
            var NumbRow = $("#txtNoofItems").val();
            var htmlvar = '';
            for (i = 0; i < NumbRow; i++) {
                htmlvar += '<tr>';
                htmlvar += '<td class="blanck-space">&nbsp;</td>';
                htmlvar += '<td class="item-number"><input type="text" id="item_number_input' + i + '" class="form-control" placeholder="Number" /></td>';
                htmlvar += '<td class="item-description"><input type="text" id="item_des_input' + i + '" class="form-control" placeholder="Number" /></td>';
                htmlvar += '<td class="item-quantity"><input type="text" id="item_quantity_input' + i + '" class="form-control" placeholder="Pieces" /></td>';
                htmlvar += '<td class="item-cost"><input type="text" id="item_cost_input' + i + '" class="form-control" placeholder="$" /></td>';
                htmlvar += '<td class="item-value"><input type="text" id="item_total_input' + i + '" class="form-control" placeholder="$" /></td>';
                htmlvar += '<td class="item-action"><a href="javascript:;" id="item_action_btn' + i + '" class="delet-icon"><img src="images/icon-delete.png" alt="" /></a></td>';
                htmlvar += '</tr>';
            }

            $('.tbody-content').append(htmlvar);

            $(".delet-icon").click(function () {
                $(this).parents("tr").remove();
            });
        });
    });
```

The textbox and link button code is:

```html
<div class="col-md-4 col-lg-2">
                                <div class="number-of-item-block">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-md-12"><asp:label runat="server" ID="lblNoofItems" Text="No. of Item Rows"></asp:label></div>
                                        <div class="col-md-12">
                                            <asp:TextBox runat="server" class="form-control" id="txtNoofItems" placeholder="#" ></asp:TextBox> <asp:Linkbutton runat="server" ID="LnkBtnNoofItems" class="btn btn-dark-blue"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i></asp:Linkbutton>
                                            <div class="row">
                                                <div class="col-md-6"></div>
                                                <div class="col-md-6"></div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
```

But the text boxes which should be generated are  controls which need to be working on server side. Please tell me how can I do this. I did not do this before and I have no idea how to do them now.

Thanks,

Deepak

Comment: Number of Questions. But foremost:
How Far did you get with your current code? Does it generate the HTML as intended?

Comment: Hello! If I understand your question correctly, you want to generate server side control, in this case a textbox. However, You can not create a server side textbox using client side scripting.

Comment: No, It did not create anything. I need to create everything now. Please suggest me a code to do this

Comment: if this answer work for you then accept the answer and close this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this may help you out..

```js
 $("#aAddMoreLicense").click(function () {
            AddMoreKeyword();
            return false;
        });

        //delete added Row or unwanted row
        function DeleteLicense($aDelete) {

            if ($(".tbl-Keyword tbody tr").length > 1) {
                $($aDelete.closest("tr")).remove();
            }
            AllowDeleteFunctionality();
        }

        function AllowDeleteFunctionality() {
            debugger
            if ($(".tbl-Keyword tbody tr").length === 2) {
                $(".tbl-Keyword tbody tr").each(function () {
                    if ($(this).attr("class") !== "hidden for-clone") {
                        $(this).find(".aDelete-Keyword").addClass("hidden");
                    }
                });
            }
            else {
                $(".tbl-Keyword tbody tr").each(function () {
                    if ($(this).attr("class") !== "hidden for-clone") {
                        $(this).find(".aDelete-Keyword").removeClass("hidden");
                    }
                });
            }
        }
AddMoreKeyword();
        function AddMoreKeyword() {

            var rowIndex = $(".tbl-Keyword tbody tr").length;
            var trItems = $(".tbl-Keyword tbody tr").eq(0).clone(true);
            trItems.removeClass("hidden for-clone");
            trItems.addClass("Keyword-row-" + rowIndex);
            $("#txtSearchKeyword", trItems).val("");
            $("#lblSrNo", trItems).addClass("Keyword-lbl-" + rowIndex);
            $("#lblSrNo", trItems).text(rowIndex);
            $("#txtSearchKeyword", trItems).addClass("Keyword-type-" + rowIndex);
            $("#ddlDomainRank1", trItems).addClass("Keyword-no-" + rowIndex);
            $(".tbl-Keyword tbody").append(trItems);

            AllowDeleteFunctionality();
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" />

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" /></script>


<div class="main-box" style="border: none; box-shadow: none">
                        <div class="main-box-body clearfix Scroll">
                            <div class="col-lg-12" style="margin: 10px 0px;">
                                <span class="mandatory" id="spnlbl" style="font-weight: bold; font-size: 12pt">*</span>
                            </div>
                            <table class="table tbl-Keyword" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th style="width: 3% !important;">
                                            Keyword Sr#
                                        </th>
                                        <th style="width: 80% !important;">
                                            <span>Keyword</span>
                                            <span style="color: red">*</span>
                                        </th>
                                        <th style="width: 15% !important;">
                                            <span >Rank</span>
                                            <span style="color: red">*</span>
                                        </th>
                                        <th style="width: 3% !important;">
                                            <span> Linked HRA</span>
                                        </th>
                                        <th style="width: 3% !important;">
                                            Delete
     </th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                    <tr class="hidden for-clone">
                                        <td style="width: 3%">
                                            <span ID="lblSrNo" ></span>
                                        </td>
                                        <td style="width: 80% !important; padding: 5px 8px;" class="td">
                                            <input type="hidden" id="hdfArtVideoId" />
                                            <input type="hidden" id="hdfType" />
         <input type="text" ID="txtSearchKeyword" CssClass="form-control" AutoCompleteType="Disabled" />                                           
                                            <div class="ac_keywordresults hidden" style="position: absolute; width: 300px; max-height: 184px; overflow: auto;">
                                            </div>

                                        </td>
                                        <td style="width: 15% !important; padding: 5px 8px;">
     <select ID="ddlDomainRank1" CssClass="form-control ddlRank" Style="padding: 6px 8px; float: left">
       <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
       <option value="saab">Saab</option>
       <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
       <option value="audi">Audi</option>
     </select>
       
                                        </td>
                                        <td style="width: 3% !important; text-align: center">
                                            <a onclick="LinkedHra(this);" class="aLContent-Keyword" style="color: #8bc34a !important; font-size: 25px" href="javascript:void(0);" title="Linked Content" target="_blank"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt"></i></a>
                                        </td>



                                        <td style="width: 3% !important; text-align: center;">
                                            <a onclick="DeleteLicense(this);" class="aDelete-Keyword" style="color: #8bc34a !important;" href="javascript:void(0);" title="Delete"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i></a>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                            <div class="col-md-12 form-group">
                                <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="aAddMoreLicense" class="lnk-morelic pull-right"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>&nbsp;Add Keywords</a>

                            </div>
                            

                        </div>
                    </div>
```